# Pre-filling request headers using classes derived from requests.Session in Python

Tags: python, session, python-requests, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to refactor some code in which many HTTP requests are made using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module. Many of these requests have (partially) the same headers, so I would like to 'pre-fill' these using [Session objects](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/).

However, I'm having difficulty making multiple inheritance work in this context. Here is what I've tried:

```
import requests, time

requestbin_URL = 'http://requestb.in/1nsaz9y1'      # For testing only; remains usable for 48 hours
auth_token = 'asdlfjkwoieur182932385'               # Fake authorization token

class AuthorizedSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, auth_token):
        super(AuthorizedSession, self).__init__()
        self.auth_token = auth_token
        self.headers.update({'Authorization': 'token=' + self.auth_token})

class JSONSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self):
        super(JSONSession, self).__init__()
        self.headers.update({'content-type': 'application/json'})

class AuthorizedJSONSession(AuthorizedSession, JSONSession):
    def __init__(self, auth_token):
        AuthorizedSession.__init__(self, auth_token=auth_token)
        JSONSession.__init__(self)

""" These two commented-out requests work as expected """
# with JSONSession() as s:
#     response = s.post(requestbin_URL, data={"ts" : time.time()})

# with AuthorizedSession(auth_token=auth_token) as s:
#     response = s.post(requestbin_URL, data={"key1" : "value1"})

""" This one doesn't """
with AuthorizedJSONSession(auth_token=auth_token) as s:
    response = s.post(requestbin_URL, data={"tag" : "some_tag_name"})
```

If I inspect the result of the last request at http://requestb.in/1nsaz9y1?inspect, I see the following:

[image]

It seems like the `Content-Type` field is correctly set to `application/json`; however, I don't see an `Authorization` header with the fake authentication token. How can I combine the `AuthorizedSession` and `JSONSession` classes to see both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the request works if I define `AuthorizedJSONSession` more simply as follows:

```
class AuthorizedJSONSession(AuthorizedSession, JSONSession):
    def __init__(self, auth_token):
        super(AuthorizedJSONSession, self).__init__(auth_token=auth_token)
```

The resulting request now has updated both the `Authorization` and `Content-Type` headers:

[image]

I've understood that when a class inherits from multiple classes which in turn inherit from the same base class, then Python is 'smart enough' to simply use `super` to initialize.

Comment: I've since switched to Python 3, in which `super` can be invoked in zero-argument form: `super().__init__(auth_token=auth_token)`.